# Toggle the editability of a QTableWidget in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I would like to be able to make a table with cells which were previously un-editable to be editable. And then control/toggle the editability of the table by attaching the function to a button.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        # last column
        #if index.column() == (index.model().columnCount() - 1):
        return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 3)
        self.setCentralWidget(table_widget)
        
        
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str('wait'))
        item_2 = QTableWidgetItem(str('wait'))
        item_3 = QTableWidgetItem(str('wait'))
        item_4 = QTableWidgetItem(str('wait'))
        item_5 = QTableWidgetItem(str('wait'))
    
        # execute the line below to every item you need locked
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item_2.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item_3.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item_4.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item_5.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        
        
        
        table_widget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        table_widget.setItem(1, 1, item_2)
        table_widget.setItem(1, 2, item_3)
        table_widget.setItem(3, 1, item_4)
        table_widget.setItem(4, 1, item_5)
        

        delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(table_widget)
        table_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the example above, the cells with items which are un-editable remain that way even though I ran the Delegate on the entire table AFTER creating and inserting those items. Is there a way to make the entire table including the un-editable cells editable?

Comment: The editability of an item completely depends on its flags, and setting an item delegate won't change nothing (especially with the above code, which doesn't do anything else than the default). If you want to restore the editability of those items, use `item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)`. Be aware that if you want to disable the editable flag, you should still keep the selectable one. You either use `setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsSelectable)`, or you *unset* the editable flag: `setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)`.

Comment: Could I make an entire table widget editable even if there are items with un-editable flags? Or do I have to do it item by item? How would that work if the data is already loaded to the table?

Comment: By default, a QStandardItem is already editable. If you want to make the whole view not editable, change its [edit triggers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop): `self.table.setEditTriggers(self.table.NoEditTriggers)`. You can restore the state with `setEditTriggers(self.table.DoubleClicked|self.table.EditKeyPressed|self.table.AnyKeyPressed)` (or any combination you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model approach solves this kind of problems in easy way: you can specify flags for specific items or whole table as function of

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Model(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, parent = None):
        super().__init__(rows, columns, parent)
        self._editable = True

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if not self._editable:
            flags = flags &~ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return flags

    def setEditable(self, editable):
        self._editable = editable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    model = Model(4, 3)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()

    checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Editable")
    checkBox.setChecked(True)
    checkBox.clicked.connect(model.setEditable)

    layout.addWidget(view)
    layout.addWidget(checkBox)
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()
    
    app.exec()
```